# Images "missing" in emulator, after build

Tags: android, html

I have built an Android App, using a jQuery Mobile index.html file "wrapped" inside Java using the Android SDK on Eclipse.
However, although the images appear OK within the Dreamweaver "Live" view for jQuery mobile,
they don't appear in the emulator in Android SDK after successful build.
I have added the image files within an image folder in the RES/mpdi folder of the project, and within the index.html file they are referenced as images/"...png" etc

Should I have changed the path in any way in the index.html file?
Also, they are 290x381 pixels - should I have had a different size for the AVD?

Thanks in advance!
David

Comment: are you using something like phonegap/jquerymobile etc?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using something like phonegap

phonegap has a whitelist that tells the app which URLs it's allowed to access. You can also add a * to it, as described http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/11/22/phonegap-gotcha-error-whitelist-rejection/  found in in the /res/xml/phonegap.xml file

Comment: No - I'm not using PhoneGap. I'm using original HTML code, generated by jQuery mobile in Dreamweaver CS6, with my own modifications. All I need to know is what is the correct format once I've added an Images folder to the res/mpdi folder - is it res/mpdi/Images/..png for each file, or is it just /Images/..png ? At the moment, something's wrong,as they don't display..